# Div does not enter the background of lightbox unless I mouse off

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, mouseevent, lightbox

I'm building a Lightbox for a video gallery. In Jquery, I've added a function which maintains the scroll position on the page so when you click out of the lightbox it brings you back to the same place as when you opened it. However, now that I have it's created a bug which keeps the active gif in front of the lightbox until you mouse off of it.

Currently, the website looks like this: imgur.com/HUy6GT1

you'll see what I mean if you click on a video and do not move your mouse. 
(Unless you open it w/ firefox because theres compatibility issues - perhaps a question for another day...)

This is the relevant jQuery:

```
function scrollPosition() {
 var tempScrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
 return $(window).scrollTop(tempScrollTop); 
 return false;
}
//LIGHTBOX -->Trigger //
 $('.lightbox_trigger').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var video_href = $(this).attr("href");
  var $lbcontent = $('#lbcontent');
  var $lightbox = $('#lightbox');
  $('.lightbox_trigger').addClass('disableClick');
//Vimeo Regex//
 function getVimeoVideoId(url){
  var regex = new RegExp(/(https?:\/\/)?(www.)?(player.)?vimeo.com\/([a-z]*\/)*([0-9]{6,11})[?]?.*/);
  if ( regex.test(url) ) {
      return regex.exec(url)[5];
  }
}
function embedVideo(video) {
        document.getElementById('embed').innerHTML = unescape(video.html);
}
var video_id = getVimeoVideoId(video_href) + '?api=1';
if ($lightbox.length > 0) {  
 $lbcontent.html('<iframe src="//player.vimeo.com/video/' + video_id +'" height="100%" width="100%" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen>' + '</iframe>') ;
  $('#lightbox').show('fast');
  $lbcontent.show();
  scrollPosition();   
}
else { 
  //create HTML markup for lightbox window     
  var lightbox = 
  '<div id="lightbox">' + 
  '<div id="lbcontent" >' + 
  '<iframe src="//player.vimeo.com/video/' + video_id +'" height="100%" width="100%" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen>' + '</iframe>'
  + '</div>' +
  '</div>';
  //insert lightbox HTML into page
  $('.site-main').append(lightbox);
  $lbcontent.show('fast');
  scrollPosition(); 
}
})
$(document).on('click', '#lightbox', function()  {
 if ($(event.target).has('#lbcontent').length) {
  $('#lightbox').hide();
  $('.entry-content').show();
  scrollPosition();
  $('.lightbox_trigger').removeClass('disableClick');
};
 if ($(event.handler).has('#lbcontent')) {
  $('#lbcontent').hide();
  $('.entry-content').show();
  $('#lbcontent iframe').attr('src', " ");
  scrollPosition();  
   $('.lightbox_trigger').removeClass('disableClick');
}
```

The weird thing is that the problem goes away if I remove the scrollPosition() function. 
Why is this happening? Whats going on here?

Comment: it works fine for me on both IE and Chrome!

Comment: Thats so weird. If i dont move the mouse at all after the click event my page looks something like this http://imgur.com/HUy6GT1

Comment: here is the behavior on my side! https://vid.me/Bwvz using chrome Version 51.0.2704.103 m  which browser are you using ?

Comment: Wow that looks good on your end. I'm using chrome Version 51.0.2704.106 (64-bit). I wonder if thats what makes the difference.